# Receiving Incoming Email on Google Compute Engine Hosted Domain?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

**Current Setup :**

- Domain registrar - Godaddy.com
- Domain Hosted on - Google Cloud Platform
- CMS - Wordpress

I have a simple Wordpress website that is hosted on the Google Cloud Platform free tier. For any emails that need to go out of Wordpress (Password reset mails / notifications etc.), I have configured SendGrid as the SMTP relay and it works perfectly.

My problem now is how to receive incoming emails ?

I just want to setup a couple of email accounts for my domain and forward / import all incoming emails to my Gmail account.

All instructions point to Gsuite, which will be an overkill at this time since I will not be using any of its features. I just need to receive occasional incoming emails.

While there are literally 100's of articles on configuring outgoing emails via SendGrid / MailJet etc., there are no useful articles on how to receive incoming emails.

Google search mostly turns up an old video about using a free Zoho account; which itself is now become a paid app.

**Tried so far :**

[1] Tried to set-up email forwarding on Godaddy. Nothing worked. Since the Nameservers are pointed to Google Cloud DNS, I believe Godaddy forwarding will not work.

[2] Checked SendGrid options, could not find anything.

[3] Trawled through Google for several hours, could not turn up anything useful.

I would sincerely appreciate any relatively straight-forward solutions / suggestions / pointers for receiving incoming emails - Either through the GCP or outside.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `mx record` to your domain that point to the IP address of the machine hosting your mail service .

- Here's how you can add the record :
  https://godaddy.com/help/add-an-mx-record-19234

Comment: Hi Ben, unfortunately, this doesn't work Since Godaddy says that it cannot display DNS information as it is being managed elsewhere. The 'elsewhere' is the CloudDNS on the Google Cloud Platform, where the website is hosted. Currently the name servers for the domain are all set to the GCP name servers. Need to figure out how to access the incoming mains on GCP itself.

Comment: I believe that there is an issue with your DNS records setup on CloudDNS. Once you have created a managed zone with all the records, you should then setup the NS records with your Domain register (GoDaddy). These NS records should point to Google CloudDNS name server records. Try looking into the following [link](https://cloud.google.com/dns/migrating#update_your_registrars_name_server_records) for more information.